# Robot.txt to allow specified URL in domain

Tags: robots.txt

I want to just allow the main URL(domain) and `http://domain/about`, and others URL are not visible to search google. Example I have link as below:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/about
http://example.com/other1
http://example.com/other2
http://example.com/other3
http://example.com/other4
http://example.com/other5
http://example.com/other6
and more URL.
```

My question what the content of robot.txt, I want to allow just `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/about` , My site use wordpress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /about
Disallow: /
```

The `$` indicates that the url string has to end there. So it won't allow, for example, `/example.com/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: http://example.com/about
Disallow: /
```

Comment: That would disallow the front page, too.